# Unable to click the Search button

Tags: node.js, button, protractor

I'm unable to click the Search button in the following HTML.  I've tried finding it using .css, .cssContaining, .className, .xpath.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
<div class="ncol-xs-offset-11 ncol-md-3 saveFilter">
    <button class="searchBtn-align">
        <i class="fa fa-search fa-lg">
        </i> Search
    </button> 
    <button class="searchBtn-align">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg">
        </i> Reset
    </button>
</div>
```

CODE

```
var buttonSearch = element(by.xpath('//button[. = " Search"]'))
browser.isElementPresent(buttonSearch).then(function (present) {
    if (present == true) {
        //buttonSearch.click();
        console.log('Search button was clicked');   
    }
    else {
        console.log('Search button was NOT located');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your xpath locator as this: `//button[contains(.,'Search')]`. and then

```
var buttonSearch = element(by.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Search')]"))
buttonSearch.isPresent().then(function (present) {
    if (present) {
        buttonSearch.click().then(()=>{
          console.log('Search button was clicked');
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Search button was NOT located');
    }
})
```

or using `async`

```
var buttonSearch = element(by.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Search')]"))

if (await buttonSearch.isPresent()) {
  await buttonSearch.click();
  console.log('Search button was clicked');   
} else {
  console.log('Search button was NOT located');
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with the locator.  I've tried with "Search" and " Search".  I was hopeful that the cssContaininText would find it... no luck with that either.  Any other options?

Comment: Attempts to verify that the button exists thru:

expect(element.all(by.xpath('//button[. = "Search"]')).count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);

results in Expected 0 to be greater than 0.

Comment: 1. this is not the locator I wrote. 2. This might be wrong way of verifying the count, unless you're using protractor 4 or less

Comment: I have Version 5.4.2

Comment: Sergey, thank you for your assistance with this!  It has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with `element(by.css('.searchBtn-align'));` ?

or even `element(by.buttonText('Search'));`